# Mongodb Array and object got mixed up inside array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

I have the below document in mongodb, where grades key is an array with the combination of objects and array. I have several records like this in my db. i wanted to update the array and have it as an object for all such records. How can i achieve this with update query ?

```
 {
        _id: 4,
        grades: [
           { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
           { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
           [{ grade: 85, mean: 85, std: 8 }]
        ]
      }
```

Expected output :

```
 {
        _id: 4,
        grades: [
           { grade: 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
           { grade: 85, mean: 90, std: 5 },
           { grade: 85, mean: 85, std: 8 }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: Not very clear on your objective.  Do you mean to say, you want to convert the last item in the "grades" array - change it from an array itself into an object?

Comment: Yes. want to convert  the array type present in "grades" to object .

Comment: Do you want to fetch the data in a specific shape (i.e., convert the nested array into a document on the fly) or do you need to actually change the shape of the data at rest (in the database)?

Comment: Need to change the shape of the document in DB. Mongo version 3.4

Comment: Do you need to change all the documents at once, or can you use the Schema Versioning pattern (change them as you encounter them in your app) ? - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-schema-versioning-pattern

Comment: Need to change all the documents @ once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do this using single update query in **MongoDB 3.4**,

##### 1) You can do 2 queries first find and second update in loop, You can execute in mongo shell or any MongoDB editor:

- `find()` query to project require field and loop the result
- `for` loop the `grades` array
- check if condition the grades element is array then concat otherwise return same
- `update()` query to update new `grades` array

```
db.getCollection('grades').find({}, { grades: 1 }).forEach(function (doc) {
    var grades = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < doc.grades.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(doc.grades[i])) {
            grades = grades.concat(doc.grades[i]);
        }
        else {
            grades.push(doc.grades[i]);
        }
    }
    // update
    db.getCollection('grades').update(
        { _id: doc._id }, 
        { $set: { grades: grades } }
    )
})
```

---

##### 2) you can try aggregation query and export updated results in the new collection using single query,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `grades` array
- `$type` to get data type of the element
- `$concatArrays` to concat multiple arrays
- `$cond` check condition if element type is array then concat directly both arrays otherwise concat with array into array
- `$out` to export collection in new collection

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      grades: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$grades",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: [{ $type: "$$this" }, "array"] },
              { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] },
              { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $out: "collection name" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PHaMQJrcolT)

---

##### 3) Alternate option using [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) query **above MongoDB 4.2**,

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
  [{
    $set: {
      grades: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$grades",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: [{ $type: "$$this" }, "array"] },
              { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] },
              { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HQVFa6f5mcQ)

Comment: This makes the assumption the nested array only has a single document entry.  Not sure this is true.

Comment: Ok atleast can we do update with some specific mentioned records with id of it ?

Comment: @Jagadeesh updated the first approach for 3.4. the second approach will work on 4.2. I yes you can give the id in query part of the find method.